# android - Set switch button into action bar with showAsAction="never"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want to put a switch button into MenuItem with showAsAction="never" but it's not working. Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.trietnhm.multipleactivities.MainActivity"
    >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="About"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_change_theme"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switcher"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_change_delimeter"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Change Delimeter"/>
</menu>
```

This my Switch button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switchForActionBar"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleX="1.3"
        android:scaleY="1.3"
        android:switchMinWidth="45dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run the app and it's not show anything. Here the image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5zsq6J-qyY5bF8tYnBKVy11OHM/view?usp=sharing

Any help I would be appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: did you use OnCreateOptionMenu and OnOptionsItemSelected methods ?

Comment: @SaTech, yes i set of course.

Comment: I give you a link image I captured: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5zsq6J-qyY5bF8tYnBKVy11OHM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try to use a title and see if it appear or not

Comment: if you make it with `app:showAsAction="always"` it ll work

Comment: are you extending appCompat activity?

Comment: @charuka: It'll work with app:showAsAction="always". but use "never" is not.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007: yes, I am. The point is use app:showAsAction="always" it works but "never" is not.

Comment: @Triet Nguyen why you want to use never is there any specific reason ?

Comment: @Charuka because I have many options (menu item) use Switch button. If I put on overflow menu which is not space enough.

Answer (score 1):

[`android:showAsAction`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

`never` :

> **Never place this item in the app bar**. Instead, list the item in the
>   app bar's overflow menu.

Of course, It won't show up. Perhaps you should use other options to show, `always` or `ifRoom`.

Answer (score 0):

This line code

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

is used with LinearLayout not with RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

why are you using app:showAsAction="Never"?? for that you can also use `app:showAsAction="ifRoom" or app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"`

Comment: because I have many options (menu item) use Switch button. If I put on overflow menu which is not space enough.