# Switch button in menu drop-down shows blank space

Tags: java, android, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to add a Switch in an options menu but for some reason instead of the custom layout it shows a blank space.

**screen_on_menu_button.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/screen_on_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:switchPadding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/menu_screen_on" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**menu.xml:**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/new_game_button"
    android:title="@string/menu_new_game"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/change_names"
    android:title="@string/menu_change_names"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/layout_change"
    android:title="@string/menu_change_layout"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<!--android:checkable="true" -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/keep_screen_on"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/screen_on_menu_button"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/help_feedback"
    android:title="@string/menu_help_feedback"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:title="@string/menu_about"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

I have tried changing `app:actionLayout` to `android:app:actionLayout`, removing the relative layout and leaving only the switch in the custom xml and all it does is add a white space between `layout_change` and `help_feedback`.
If I set *showAsAction* to always it is displayed in the *ActionBar* but this is not what I intend to do.
Also, I have the option to remove the switch and set the menu item as *checkable*, but again this is not intended and most similar cases provide what I have already implemented.

So, how can I integrate that switch inside the drop down options menu?

Comment: You can't do that if you want to use  app:showAsAction="never"; but you can achieve it with  app:showAsAction="always" . check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414056/android-set-switch-button-into-action-bar-with-showasaction-never >>> you can alternatively open a new dialog or activity for changing the list of settings

Comment: also you can use android:checkable="true" in your menu item instead of a switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add custom layout in the dropdown menu. It accepts `<item>` or `<group>` only. The other option can be to use `<item>` with `android:checkable` and change the default checked state depending on the value.
The other options can be

1. replace the menu with PopupWindow
2. display the switch in actionbar using `app:showAsAction="always"`.

Comment: Went for checkable since it's simpler to implement and at least close to what I want to achieve